# Introduction "on" or Introduction "to", which one is more appropriate and idiomatic?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, expressions

the title of section 2.1 of book "Deep Learning and Convolutional Neural Networks for Medical Image Computing" is

> Introduction on Deep Learning Methods in Mammography

I see Introduction "to" more than Introduction "on", so, which one is more appropriate and idiomatic?

Comment: “Introduction to” is the idiomatic expression

Answer (score 0):

They mean slightly different things. In this instance, [introduction](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/introduction) means something that introduces, or is a preliminary, to something else.

> : something that introduces: such as
>
> a(1) : a part of a book or treatise preliminary to the main portion
>
> (2) : a preliminary treatise or course of study

If it were "introduction to," instead of "introduction on," the emphasis would not be on what the introduction is about, but what it is supposed to do: help you understand, in this case, deep learning methods in Mammography.

According to [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=introduction%20on%2C%20introduction%20to&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cintroduction%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cintroduction%20to%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cintroduction%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cintroduction%20to%3B%2Cc0), "introduction to" is vastly more common, but without more context, I can't say which I think is more appropriate.

Comment: Thank you. Would you please make up some contexts where "introduction to" and "introduction on" would be used respectively?

Answer (score 0):

It’s almost always “introduction to” a subject, not “introduction on”.

I read a pdf I found of this section of the book, and in context, they should have said “introduction to”.  The excerpt I read had a bunch of other minor errors, which makes me think the authors are not native speakers.  (Like, they say ‘summary on’ not ‘summary of’.)

Comment: Thank you. Would you please explain a bit more about why they should have said “introduction to”?